# c++ invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

Tags: c++

I have this snippet of code:

```
void read_from_file(){
    ifstream fin;
    int index=-1;
    fin.open("eliza.dat");
    char line[MAX_RESP_LEN];
    while(fin){
        fin.getline(line,MAX_RESP_LEN);
        char *ptr = 0;
        ptr = strstr("@KWD@",line);
        if(strlen(line)<1){
            break;
        }
        else if(ptr!=NULL){
            // the next line is a keyword
            fin.getline(line,MAX_RESP_LEN);
            keys[++index].addword(line);
        }
        else{
            // it is a response
            keys[index].addresp(line);
        }    
    }
}
```

and an additional file with keywords marked with @KWD@, but when I compile this this error occurs:

`error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
  ptr = strstr("@KWD@",line);`

I have this files included:

- ostream
- iostream
- conio.h
- unistd.h
- string
- time.h
- ctime
- math.h
- stdlib.h
- cstring
- cstdlib
- stdio.h
- fstream.h

Is there anything missing? Or do the error occur before this function? The code has 400 lines so I cannot copy everything.

Comment: You passed constant data into `strstr` and got a pointer to constant data back. Being able to modify it would cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ptr = strstr("@KWD@",line);
```

change it to

```
ptr = strstr(line,"@KWD@");
```